# Loose location accuracy problem

Tags: gps, google-maps, google-maps-navigation, external-gps

It is very annoying to calibrate my Samsung Galaxy A53 compass every  3 minutes when I navigate in big city. In many places accuracy becomes low after several minutes of navigation. I have feeling that when phone is connected to car navigation is better.

How to solve loose accuracy problem in general?

Does using more expensive Android phone can solve the problem?
Should I move to Apple?

Can I somehow connect external GPS module with compass like I suppose is done in car?

Comment: We had recently the question how to disable magnetic compass for navigation and use only GNSS. For vehicles that move compass is not needed, only if you stop or move slowly like walking compass is often better (if it works correctly). If a compass doesn't work reliable I would assume that the phone was just designed in a bad way. IMHO it says more about the manufacturer that the platform. I headed that a lot of modern phones don't have a compass at all, may be because this loose calibration too easy?